# Clustering with Jboss EAP and Load balancing with Haproxy

Tags: load-balancing, cluster, haproxy, high-availability, jboss

I'm doing load balancing with HAProxy and use JBoss EAP as application servers.

The Haproxy server is configured to route incoming requests to the application servers.

How can I integrate Jboss EAP and HAproxy to have both clustering and load balancing so sessions are replicated on servers?

Comment: Which version of Jboss EAP are you using. At the end the process is like: 1. Configure your Jboss EAP installations on a cluster (dependes on the version different approaches are used) 2. configure your war application to be distributable (on web.xml add tar `<distributable/>`)